# v-data-table checked validate v-text-field type number

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

How do I validate a number input field inside v-data-table? I want to set required only on checked row.

[image: enter]

here's my code

```
<v-data-table
  v-model="selected"
  :headers="dataHeaders"
  :items="mealTimes"
  show-select
  @click:row="setTime"
>
  <template #[`item.data-table-select`]="{ item, isSelected }">
    <v-simple-checkbox
      :value="isSelected"
      color="primary"
      :ripple="false"
      @input="setSelected(item, isSelected)"
    />
  </template>
  <template #[`item.weight`]="{ item }">
      <div class="w-100">
        <v-text-field 
          v-model="item.weight"
          :value="item.weight"
          type="number"
          :rules="myRule"
          outlined
          dense
        /> 
      </div>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Rules

```
data: () => ({
  myRule: [ 
    v => Number.isInteger(Number(v)),
    v => ( Number(v) && Number(v) >= 1 ) || 'Min: 1',
    v => ( Number(v) && Number(v) <= 99 ) || 'Max: 99',
  ],
}),
```

I only need to validate the input for the selected row, can anybody help me how to validate between checked box and v-text-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional syntax to put correct set of rules for your number field:

```js
<v-data-table
  v-model="selected"    
  item-key="name"
  show-select
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  :items-per-page="5"
>
  <template #[`item.calories`]="{ item }">
    <div class="w-100">
      <v-text-field 
        v-model="item.weight"
        :value="item.weight"
        type="number"
        :rules="selected.find(it => it.name === item.name) !== undefined ? myRule : []"
        outlined
        dense
      /> 
    </div>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
...
data () {
  return {
    myRule: [ ...your rules ],
    selected: [ ...selected values ],
    headers: [ ... ],
    desserts: [ ... ]
  }
}
```

[CodePen playground is here](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/xxzwEEP)